# Получить результат метода

Tags: java, android, json, ооп

Имеется метод:

```
public static boolean sendAuthenticationCode(String code, String phone){
        token = MyApplication.getWritableDatabase().getToken();
        isOk = false;
        final JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {
            params.put("phone", phone);
            params.put("code", code);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT,
                Constant.REGISTER_PHONE_CODE, params,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        isOk = Parser.getAuthenticationCode(response);
                        Log.d(TAG, "isOkSet = " + isOk);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                isOk = false;
                Log.d(TAG, "ErrorResponse = " + isOk);
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("auth_token", token.getToken());
                return headers;
            }
        };
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
        return isOk;
    }
```

Нужно присвоить возвращаемое значение данного метода переменной.
Например:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean a = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                a = MyClass.sendAuthenticationCode(code, phone);
            }
        });
    }
```

Метод запускается после присвоения, и значение а остается false. Как побороть?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С таким построением никак. Попробую объяснить. Вы в методе запускаете в отдельном потоке отправку sendAuthenticationCode:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT,
            Constant.REGISTER_PHONE_CODE, params,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    isOk = Parser.getAuthenticationCode(response);
                    Log.d(TAG, "isOkSet = " + isOk);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            isOk = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "ErrorResponse = " + isOk);
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("auth_token", token.getToken());
            return headers;
        }
    };
```

Затем, пока у вас еще невыполнился запрос, вы делаете

```
return isOk;
```

при этом значение isOk остается прежним, пока не выполнился запрос и не вызвал:

```
@Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    isOk = Parser.getAuthenticationCode(response);
                    Log.d(TAG, "isOkSet = " + isOk);
                }
```

Вывод: Вы получите реальное значение isOk только в колбэке onResponse.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Реализовал то что мне нужно AsynkTask’ом.

Comment: Хороший выбор для вашего случая.